# In JavaScript, how to access object properties inside an array of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following array of object and I am trying to access tester transaction's amount and status?

[image: Output]

I am able to display company's and project's name via the following:

```
transactions.map((transaction, index) => {
    console.log(transaction.company_name)
    console.log(transaction.project_name)
})
```

How would I display the status and the amount which is part of tester_transaction object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
transactions.map((transaction, index) => {
    if(transaction.hasOwnProperty("company_name")){
       console.log(transaction.company_name);
    }
    if(transaction.hasOwnProperty("company_name")){
       console.log(transaction.project_name);
    }
    if(transaction.hasOwnProperty("tester_transaction")){
       console.log(transaction.tester_transaction.amount);
    }
    if(transaction.hasOwnProperty("tester_transaction")){
       console.log(transaction.tester_transaction.status);
    }
});
```

Don't forget to check for that the property exists.

Comment: why `map` ? when you just have to access it!

Comment: RyuH used a map in his original code. What map does is it creates a new array based on the method passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `.tester_transaction` object and its properties directly from `transaction` (and check if `tester_transaction` is defined):

```
transactions.map((transaction, index) => {
    console.log(transaction.company_name)
    console.log(transaction.project_name)

    if (transaction.tester_transaction !== undefined) {
      console.log(transaction.tester_transaction.status)
      console.log(transaction.tester_transaction.amount)
    }
})
```

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't work. I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`

Comment: Then it means that not all `transaction` have a `tester_transaction` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
    transactions.map((t) => {
    console.log(t. tester_transaction.amount)
  console.log(t.status)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This code violates the use of Map.

Read more about map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Please use simple `for of..` loop as your purpose is to just fetch the value and print it.

```
for(const transaction of transactions) {
  console.log(transaction.company_name || '');
  console.log(transaction.project_name || '');

  if(!transaction. tester_transaction)
    continue;

  console.log(transaction.tester_transaction.amount || '');
  console.log(transaction.tester_transaction.status || '');
}
```